# Creating a Dataframe from an excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import an excel and create a dataframe using pandas read_excel function.

The thing is I only need to use columns C to F and rows 17 onward from the excel. How can I select only that part of the excel file and transform it to a dataframe in pandas???

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: pls add your code

Comment: import pandas as pd
energia = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls')
energia

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `usecols` parameter to select the columns of interest in your spreadsheet, and `skiprows` to select everything below row 17.

`import pandas as pd
 pd.read_excel('my_spreadsheet.xlsx', usecols='C:F', skiprows=16)`